# Windows 7: The audio service is not running?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

Why isn't my audio service running?  It's so random.  Sometimes I am able to change my PC volumn, other times I am not.

I've restarted the following services:

- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- Multimedia Class Scheduler
- Windows Audio Endpoint Builder

I think I started noticing this after I went mucking around in msconfig looking for ways to improve PC performance.  I know I shut off some services, but that was over 6 months ago today and I am finally getting tired of it happening.

Comment: Are you saying that the service start on boot, but then sometimes stops while you are using Windows? If so, then either it is crashing for some reason or something is stopping it. Either way, Event Log (`eventvwr`) under Services and System to narrow down *when* it happened to see if you can find out what other stuff was happening at that moment.

Comment: I should have noted that I found no relevant services that weren't running.  I just restarted them for good measure.  I'll look into the event log.

Comment: Have you tried updating (or just reinstalling) your audio device drivers?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but have you tried running the "Audio Troubleshooter"? This happened once on another PC I was using and the troubleshooter fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The most important one is simply `Windows Audio`.

Make sure that this is set to automatic start and is currently started - it should start dependencies automatically and should also be all that is required for audio to work.

Comment: @Synetech - AFAIK, Windows Audio Endpoint Builder is a dependency of Windows Audio, so, starting Windows Audio should start it automatically... unless I got it the wrong way round? :/

Comment: @Synetech Just checked, and yep... Endpoint builder will automatically start, along with other services when you start Windows Audio

Comment: but, it is a dependency of Windows Audio, so, if it was to stop or fail, Windows Audio would also fail... so, if Windows Audio is working - Windows Audio Endpoint Builder will also be working :/ Sorry, I think we are going around in circles / I am a little confused here!

Answer (score 1):

Is the audio running under device manager?

In device manager if you right click on your audio it should display disable (meaning it is enabled).

[image]

Or maybe you need to update the driver.

Answer (score -2):

Enable the Power service, as it appears to be needed for audio to work even on workstations.

Comment: Could you explain how to "enable the Power service"?

Answer (score -2):

pita

press the windows key + R, or star run and then type in "msconfig".
Go to the Services tab and press enable all.
Then go to the Start up tab and do the same.
Restart.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you provided some context around what you're telling the OP to do and why you think this will solve their problem.